# confused by error code in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

My code is producing error "Error of type 'Average.Module1.student' cannot be converted to '1 dimensional array of Average.Module1.student." on line 15.  What am I overlooking?

Module Module1
Imports System

```
Class student
    Public id As Integer
    Public name As String
    Public M1 As Integer
    Public M2 As Integer
    Public objStudent As String
    Public Function average() As Double
        Return (M1 + M2) / 2
    End Function
End Class
Class Program
    Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim objstudent() As student = New student()

        Dim s As student
        For i As Integer = 0 To 14
            s = New student()
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Student id")
            s.id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Student Name")
            s.name = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the first mark")
            s.M1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the second mark")
            s.M2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
            objstudent(i) = s
        Next
        For Each ss As student In objstudent
            Dim a As Double = ss.average()
            If a >= 90 Then
                Console.WriteLine(ss.name + "Your grade is A")
            ElseIf (a >= 80) AndAlso (a < 90) Then
                Console.WriteLine(ss.name + "Your grade is B")
            ElseIf (a >= 70) AndAlso (a < 80) Then
                Console.WriteLine(ss.name + "Your grade is C")
            ElseIf (a >= 60) AndAlso (a < 70) Then
                Console.WriteLine(ss.name + "Your grade is D")
            Else
                Console.WriteLine(ss.name + "Sorry, You failed")
            End If

     Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

End Module

Comment: `Dim objstudent() As student = New student()` says I want an array of students named `objstudent` then tries to initialize it as one single student object.  It is (sort of) declared, but when you try to put something it it it will fail because you didnt tell it how big.  The code should also fail because IMPORTS need to precede any other code.

Comment: Declare your objstudent with _Dim objstudent(15) As student_ but I really suggest you to use a _List(Of Student)_

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim objstudent() As student = New student()
```

This is not correct array declaration. You declare that you want an array of students but you use the Student constructor. So you are actual tell:

```
new array = new object
```

Here is the correct declaration. Note that arrays are 0-based. So:

```
Dim objstudent As student() = New student(14) {}
```

is an array of 15 students.

```
Class student
    Public id As Integer
    Public name As String
    Public M1 As Integer
    Public M2 As Integer
    Public objStudent As String
    Public Function average() As Double
        Return (M1 + M2) / 2
    End Function
End Class
Class Program
    Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim objstudent As student() = New student(14) {}

        Dim s As student
        For i As Integer = 0 To 14
            s = New student()
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Student id")
            s.id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Student Name")
            s.name = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the first mark")
            s.M1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the second mark")
            s.M2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
            objstudent(i) = s
        Next
        For Each ss As student In objstudent
            Dim a As Double = ss.average()
            If a >= 90 Then
                Console.WriteLine(ss.name + "Your grade is A")
            ElseIf (a >= 80) AndAlso (a < 90) Then
                Console.WriteLine(ss.name + "Your grade is B")
            ElseIf (a >= 70) AndAlso (a < 80) Then
                Console.WriteLine(ss.name + "Your grade is C")
            ElseIf (a >= 60) AndAlso (a < 70) Then
                Console.WriteLine(ss.name + "Your grade is D")
            Else
                Console.WriteLine(ss.name + "Sorry, You failed")
            End If

     Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: you could at least provide some explanation to the PO in your answer

Comment: @AlexB.Just did. ;-)